# android asus zenfone 5 not detected on ubuntu os

Tags: android, ubuntu

I have an asus zenfone 5, i want to develop android application on it and i am currently use ubuntu as my only OS,

what im already did was :

1. enabled usb debugging but still not detected in my computer
2. when i type lsusb on terminal the phone detected as Bus 002 Device 006: ID 18d1:d002 Google Inc.

these are my detail information about the system that i used, in case someone ask

1. OS : ubuntu 12.04 /elementary luna 64 bit
2. Android Device : zenfone 5 with android version 4.4.2

thanks^^

Comment: You may need to add something to your `udev` rules. http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, after follow your instruction my device detected as EBAZBC00X118[OFFLINE] on android studio, then what i should do next?

Comment: Did a dialog appear on the device, prompting you to confirm whether you want to allow debugging from your Ubuntu machine? If not, unplug and re-plug in the device, to try to trigger that dialog to appear, then accept the dialog.

Comment: oh wow, thank you so much @CommonsWare ^^ , could you re write your answer in answer column, because i cant mark your answer in comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many times, on Ubuntu, "it just works" -- you plug in the device, you accept the "yes, I want to allow debugging from this PC" dialog on the device, and you are set.

Sometimes, though, you need to customize your `udev` rules. Instructions for this can be found in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up). Search engines can usually turn up the rules you need, if your device is reasonably popular.

So, for example, here are some lines from the `51-android.rules` set of `udev` rules on my development machine:

```
# Acer A700
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666"

# LG
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666"

# HTC
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

# SONY
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666"

# ASUS
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666"

# Rikomagic
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666"

# Kindle Fire HDX
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1949", MODE="0666"

# Qualcomm MDP 800
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666"

# Nokia X
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0421", MODE="0666"

# hudl 2
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d4d", ATTR{idProduct}=="504b", MODE="0666"
```

I usually then restart `udev` via **`service udev restart`**, before plugging the device in again. Then, if the device has debugging enabled, you should get the confirmation dialog on the device, and if you accept that dialog, you will be able to use development tools to work with that device (set breakpoints, inspect LogCat, etc.).